# Class 'App\Validator' not found laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

please help im getting this error when creating an login and registration page in laravel 5.1

```
FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 44:
Class 'App\Validator' not found
```

here is my AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

and my register view

```
<!-- resources/views/auth/register.blade.php -->

<form method="POST" action="/QADapps/auth/register">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Name
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        Confirm Password
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

all of the codes are from laravel documention. that's why i dont know why it fails. please check where i get the error. thank you

also this is my routes controller

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

P.S. my app is under the domain of
http://localhost:8080/QADapps/auth/register
 is there any issue because of that?
i also move index.php and .htaccess from public into the root directory

Comment: Do you have the `Validator` or the `User` class inside your `app` folder?

Comment: hello,where is the exact location?

Comment: `app/Validator.php`. If this file does not exist, you can try @delatbabel answer below.

Comment: should i create a validator model?? i cannot see a validator.php under app director. sorry im new to laravel

Answer (score 53):

You actually need either this:

```
use Validator;
```

or this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Illuminate\Validation\Validator is the underlying class containing the functionality but to use the static methods you need to pull in the facade class.

The facade class Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator is aliased to Validator in config/app.php

Comment: hi, when i use both nothing happens it just redirect me to registration page. but didnt save into db

Comment: You should check the result of your User::create() call, I can't see your database structure but maybe there was a DB error there.

Comment: i tried User::create() and it save one data to my database.

Comment: thanks 
       use Validator;
it's help me to fix my issue.

Answer (score 2):

May be late here but might help someone later, this is what save 
`use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;`

Answer (score 0):

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
>
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

and

> $validator = \Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

[Detail Solution:](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/class-apphttpcontrollersvalidator-not-found)

Answer (score -1):

try only

```
use Validator;
```

it will work fine!